# sourceModel()->createIndex() in QAbstractProxyModel sub-class

Tags: c++, qt, model

**I am attempting to create a proxy model that dynamically maps items from source model.**

Following the implementation of `QIdentityProxyModel` with the intention to go from there I have discovered that it is in fact impossible to replicate it by examining the 4 core functions:

```
mapFromSource()
mapToSource()
index()
parent()
```

Consider this based on `QIdentityProxyModel`:

*mapFromSource()*

```
QModelIndex ProxyModel::mapFromSource(const QModelIndex &sourceIndex) const
{
    if(sourceIndex.isValid())
        return createIndex(sourceIndex.row(), sourceIndex.column(), sourceIndex.internalPointer());
    else
        return QModelIndex();
}
```

*mapToSource()*

```
QModelIndex ProxyModel::mapToSource(const QModelIndex &proxyIndex) const
{
    if(proxyIndex.isValid())
        return sourceModel()->createIndex(proxyIndex.row(), proxyIndex.column(), proxyIndex.internalPointer());
    else
        return QModelIndex();
}
```

*index()*

```
QModelIndex ProxyModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    const QModelIndex sourceParent = mapToSource(parent);
    const QModelIndex sourceIndex = sourceModel()->index(row, column, sourceParent);
    return mapFromSource(sourceIndex);
}
```

*parent()*

```
QModelIndex ProxyModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    const QModelIndex sourceIndex = mapToSource(index);
    const QModelIndex sourceParent = sourceIndex.parent();
    return mapFromSource(sourceParent);
}
```

**THE ISSUE**

Problem lies in `mapToSource()` line

```
return sourceModel()->createIndex(proxyIndex.row(), proxyIndex.column(), proxyIndex.internalPointer());
```

The `QAbstractItemModel::createIndex` is protected function and cannot be used unless the caller is declared friend. That is obviously not an option without modifying the `QAbstractItemModel` class directly. The only alternative is to use regular `QAbstractItemModel::index` but that requires parent in form of `QModelIndex` as one of the arguments. However doing this:

```
return sourceModel()->index(proxyIndex.row(), proxyIndex.column(), proxyIndex.parent());
```

causes an infinite loop due to the fact that `parent()` function relies on `mapToSource()` **and vice versa now**.

The alternative approach shown [for example here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/01/12/qt-commercial-support-weekly-10-sorting-filtering-and-advanced-manipulation-with-proxy-models-2/) relies on the stored map of `QPersistentModelIndex` objects that are queried in the above mentioned functions. This approach while viable has several disadvantages:

- It requires a lots of extra memory to store the indexes
- All persistent indexes need to be updated by the source model upon every structure change (as opposed to on demand index lookup with dynamic models)
- Queries to the map may be slow when iterating over kyes of the map (this can be remedied by making two identical maps in reverse at the expense of yet more memory)

Hence my questions:

*Is there another way to handle the hierarchical proxy model dynamically without relying on createIndex() and without running into infinite loop of function calls?*

*Is it in fact necessary to create and maintain the structure of the proxy model in a storage vis-à-vis the source structure or is there a way to create a dynamic proxy model?*

Thanks!

Comment: I am facing the same problem and the answer is apparently creating a overly complicated code that uses `QPersistentIndex` like you said, which definately is not worth the time spent. Apparently the best you can do is to bind to the row addition and such events and storing the required persistent indices in an efficient lookup structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is a late reply, but I've just faced the same problem. I solved it by casting *sourceModel()* to my model, meanwhile I declared my `ProxyModel` as a friend.

This is my *mapToSource* definition:

```
QModelIndex ProxyModel::mapToSource(const QModelIndex& proxyIndex) const
{
   Model* pModel = qobject_cast<Model*>(sourceModel());
   if (!pModel || !proxyIndex.isValid()) return QModelIndex();

   ...
   return pModel->createIndex(row, col, proxyIndex.internalPointer());
}
```

and the friend declaration:

```
class Model : public QAbstractTableModel
{
   Q_OBJECT

   friend class ProxyModel;
   ...
};
```

I understand your concern about using only QAbstractItemModel interface (believe me, I had the same), but let's face it the `ProxyModel` can only be used with my `Model` and nothing else (at least according to my implementation). Therefore I don't see anything bad in "friendship" like this. As for UB there shouldn't be any issues here as well, because `qobject_cast` would return `0` if other model other than mine was provided.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code please? I do not think casting objects to types the are NOT is all that good idea. I imagine one could use a wrapper class and only accept that in the ProxyModel but that would be breaking the Qt interface. Or do you cast into such a wrapper? I think technically it should work but it definitely smells like UB to me even if the goal is just to expose something that you know is actually there. Anyway, I am curious about your solution!

Comment: @Resurrection Me neither, but I thought that was the fair trade-off after all. I will post the code as soon as I get home later today.

Comment: @Resurrection I posted the relevant code and my explanation. I noticed you're from Prague. We've just came from a short vacation from Prague a few days ago..

Comment: Thanks! It seems fine to me. I was expecting something wild like casting *any* sourceModel to your friend-declared wrapper model (that could in theory work as well perhaps if one never touches anything but QAbstractItemModel methods but maybe it would not because of different layout of classes so the pointer offset would mess up as it would assume different layout). And yeah, Prague is great. Hope you enjoyed it. :-)

Comment: Why is CreateIndex protected anyway? I am in proxy, but i want to create index from sourceModel(), because i want that my QModelIndex contains the correct model for my row and index. Qt is such a headache sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

Building on the previous answers, I would like to add some alternate ways

First, the uglyest hack in the history of time itself is safe-ish on most compile:

```
class HackyDummy : public QAbstractItemModel
{
   friend class ProxyModel;
};

QModelIndex ProxyModel::createSourceIndex(int r, int c, void *i) {
    return ((HackyDummy*) sourceModel())->createIndex(r,c,i);
}
```

Now, of course, this is a terrible, terrible hack. It also wont compile in some compiler as the C++ spec isn't very clear (or at least as been mis-interpreted by some) on accessing parent class private and protected methods from sub-class friends. This lead us to a better plan. But first, a little detail: QIdentityProxyModel does it (almost). QIdentityModel own mapToSource/mapFromSource are public and re-implementable, so is its createIndex. So, it is possible do an internal/private QIdentityProxyModel with a method to create our little source indices from the row, column and internal pointers by accessing the hack contained inside of QIdentityProxyModel itself.

Edit: typo

Answer (score 1):

I just inherited from QIdentityProxyModel and used it's mapToSource method in my mapToSourceMethod.

```
QModelIndex PropertyModel::mapToSource(const QModelIndex & proxyIndex) const
{
    if(hasNoModel())
    {
        return QModelIndex();
    }

    QModelIndex remapped = createIndex( /* transform proxyIndex here */ );

    return QIdentityProxyModel::mapToSource(remapped);
}
```

It means you don't end up with a cast that could crash your code should you ever change the source model type and forget to update your cast.